# Why does "is T" cause compilation error with generics in Kotlin, while "as T" behaves as expected?

Tags: kotlin, generics

```
fun <T> example(): T {
    val obj = Any()
    return obj as T // compile
}

fun <T> example2(): Boolean {
    val obj = Any()
    return obj is T // doesn't compile
}
```

I would appreciate an explanation of the reasons behind this behavior and any possible approaches to addressing the issue.

Comment: Casting is a way to tell the compiler, "Trust me, I know what I'm doing". It's for when you know more about the type of an object than the compiler. Generics are a way to reduce the need of casting by giving more information to the compiler, allowing it to insert *checked* casts for you. However, generics only exist at compile-time. At run-time, the `T` in your code is not a "real" type. Your cast is an *unchecked* cast. The compiler allows it, because the developer might know what they're doing, but the cast can still fail at run-time (e.g., `val str = example<String>()` would fail).

Comment: You can get around it by trying to cast, returning true if it works, and catching the exception to return false if it doesn't. Ugly, but it will do the job.

Comment: you can use `inline fun` and `reified T` to achieve what you expect: https://marketsplash.com/tutorials/kotlin/kotlin-reified/